Remix vite UNRESOLVED_IMPORT - relative import error
I’m migrating a remix project from esbuild to vite.
It’s giving error in roll up as shown in the pic.
error image
The issue is in referencing the files.
This relative (dot) import doesn’t work.
import { DataContextAppLayout } from "./components/Layout/DataContextAppLayout";

However, this ~ import works.
import { DataContextAppLayout } from "~/components/Layout/DataContextAppLayout";

I have 500+ files, really don’t wanna change how I import. How do I make the relative imports work?
It builds fine locally, even with vercel build but doesn’t work when deployed to vercel.
Packages:
        "vite": "^5.3.1",
        "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.3.2"
        "node": ">=18.0.0"
        "@remix-run/dev": "^2.15.1",
        "@remix-run/node": "^2.15.1",
...

vite.config.ts
import { vitePlugin as remix } from "@remix-run/dev";
import { installGlobals } from "@remix-run/node";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

installGlobals();

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [remix(), tsconfigPaths()],
    ssr: {
        noExternal: [/^d3.*$/, /^@nivo.*$/],
    },
});

tsconfig.json
{
    "include": [
        "**/*.ts",
        "**/*.tsx",
        "**/.server/**/*.ts",
        "**/.server/**/*.tsx",
        "**/.client/**/*.ts",
        "**/.client/**/*.tsx"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ES2022"],
        "types": ["@remix-run/node", "vite/client"],
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "target": "ES2022",
        "strict": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "~/*": ["./app/*"]
        },

        // Vite takes care of building everything, not tsc.
        "noEmit": true
    }
}

The same packages and config are working fine for another project so I don’t know how to recreate it.
This is the template I’m using for both the working one and the not working one. I haven’t made any changes to entry files or any other files.
